# Get checked radio value iteratively

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button, checked

I've looked through and tried just about every jquery radio button value checking solution here, but I can't get anything to work for me (except in isolation).  I even thought I'd found (and posted in response to my own question) a solution. Nada.

In the script below, what is the appropriate jquery code to get and store the value of the checked radio button from the "curForm" so that it will be available outside the while function?

```
 while (prevForm != "sympFormEtiology") {
$('div').hide();
curForm = getForm();
$('div#'+ curForm).show();

      $(insert relevant code here)

prevForm = curForm;
}
```

The html looks like this:

```
 <div id="sympFormTemporPatt" class = "main">
<form class="sympCodeForm" action="">
<p class="formTQuestion">Which of the following best describes...? </p>
<input type="radio" name="temporpatt" value="1" > Acute<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="temporpatt" value="2" > Continuous<br><br>
    ...
    </form>
 </div>
```

Very important! There are 12 forms, with 12 Ids and each one has different radio nane="something".

Thank you.

Comment: `$('input').is(":checked")` or `$('input:checked')` can check if the input is checked.

Comment: Define an array outside loop, fetch radios using `$('selector').each(function() { });` and use `.push` to store data inside array.

Answer (score 0):

considering
 `$('div#'+ curForm)` as current form the code below will select all radio inputs in current form:

```
$('div#'+ curForm).find('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function(){
     // myArray.push($(this).attr('name')) or myArray.push($(this).attr('id')) or whatever you want
    });
```

Comment: well he says that the selected form is `$('div#'+ curForm)` so my code will select all radio inputs which are checked. right?

Comment: yep, please attach this to the answer so the person who asked it and others could learn from it. code only answers are considered low-quality posts.

Comment: OK, I understand how you are selecting all the radio inputs with the divID and the .each.  But, being a newbie, this answer is somewhat incomplete for me: I don't understand why you are pushing data to an array and how to get it out later.  If it helps, I need to take the value of the selected button from each form and concat them into variable later.

Comment: If I could add one more request.  I'd like to test the function with an alert() so that I can see what value it is returning.  Sorry for adding on reqs.  New to the board.

Comment: This did NOT work for me.  It simply ran through all of the forms, show and hide each until it exited the while loop.

Comment: well you must say what exactly you want to do.